# Is there an option for ghosting in armature in blender 2.8?

Tags: armature

There is no ghost settings in armature properties in blender 2.8. Is there any other way to access it?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/rigging/armatures/properties/ghost.html#:~:text=The%20ghosts%20settings%20are%20found%20in%20the%20Armature%20tab.&text=This%20will%20display%20a%20given,at%20the%20most%20distant%20frames.

Answer (score 1):

I have found (but not yet tested) this Add-on for Blender 2.80 which claims to do onion skinning (a.k.a. ghosting) on any mesh objects: https://blendermarket.com/products/onion-skin-tools